# How do I get the dev tools of redux to work with jest and enzymes

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Hi can you help please.

Why do my tests break with this redux store setup.

If I comment out the redux dev tools it works?

```
    // window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import reducers from './Reducers'
import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise'

const store = (initialState) => createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      reduxPromise
    ),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default ({children, initialState ={}}) => (
  <Provider store={store(initialState)}>
    {children}
  </Provider>
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that was given to me, and it works

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import reducers from './Reducers'
import reduxPromise from 'redux-promise'

const store = (initialState) => {
  const composeEnhancers =
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

  return createStore(
    reducers,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxPromise))
  )
};

export default ({ children, initialState = {} }) => (
  <Provider store={store(initialState)}>
    {children}
  </Provider>
);
```